# running the application on controller

Tags: spring-boot, service

I'm still a beginner with spring boot, I'm using spring JPA to fetch the data from multiple tables in the same database and everything going fine, I used to run my application at the `Main` but here I have added a `Controller` class and running things there, then i used `@Scheduled(fixedRate=7000)` instead of creating an infinite loop to keep check the data from db and stay live, the application working fine but as far as at the running time application executed twice  instead of once at the beginning before scheduling, a is there any idea about what happened here :

Mainclass :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class AccessingDataJpaApplication {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
    }
}
```

`Controller` class :

```
@Controller
@EnableScheduling
public class MainController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainController.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    private Set<String> camps = new HashSet<String>();

    @Bean
    @Scheduled(fixedRate=7000)
    public void run(){
        logger.info("Running");
        if((customerRepository.findAllByStatusAndCampType(0, 1).size()) > 0 ){
            for(Customer customer : customerRepository.findAll()){
                System.out.println(customer.getCampCd());
                camps.add(customer.getCampCd());
                }
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------"); 
            for(MessageCampain messagecampain : messageRepository.findAllByCampCdIn(camps)) {
                System.out.println(messagecampain.toString());
                }
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
            for(String value : camps) {
                System.out.println(value);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

execution log :

```
[           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
[           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[           main] c.e.accessingdatajpa.MainController      : Running
[           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
[           main] c.e.a.AccessingDataJpaApplication        : Started AccessingDataJpaApplication in 5.467 seconds (JVM running for 6.242)
[   scheduling-1] c.e.accessingdatajpa.MainController      : Running
[   scheduling-1] c.e.accessingdatajpa.MainController      : Running
```

you can notice that at `Running` word

Comment: why are you using `@Bean` annotation on `run` method. I think it's causing it to call it for first time and then `@Scheduled` is calling it second time

Comment: @ShrikantHavale I'm still a beginner can you show me what should I do at the controller ?, should i replace `bean` annotation with something else?

Comment: As you are using `@Controller`, I assume you want to expose this method to be called somehow from FE. if you don't want to expose this functionality at all to UI, then `@Controller` is not really the correct one to use. Try `@Service` or `@Component.`

Comment: @it worked fine after remove `bean` annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you annotate the `run()` in `MainController` as `@Bean` , which will creates a [`lite`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts) mode bean called `run`. (Spring represents this bean as the type of `NullBean` internally)

So , the 1st call of 'Running' in the main thread is due to spring instantiate this `run` bean. The remaining calls of 'Running' in the scheduling-1 thread are due to the the effect of `@Scheduled`. So please remove `@Bean` from the `run()` as it does not have any points to create a null bean ...

```java
@Scheduled(fixedRate=7000)
public void run(){


}
```